# How do I choose a text length with a custom Tweet button?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm working on a custom blog page and trying to add social media links, which I've never done before and it is turning out to be very time consuming. I'm on Twitter right now and am trying to add a custom Tweet Button because I need to visually style it. I understand how to set the properties of the URL (in javascript) to make it work, but I'm confused on what the best way to make sure it stays inside the 140 character limit is. The tweet will include the link, which twitter will shorten to a t.co link, so I don't know the actual length of this link or how many characters are left available. I want to fit in as much of my blog's title, body, and hash tags as possible. How do you go about doing this?

I see that you can use the API's GET help/configuration to find the max length of a t.co link. To do that it looks like you must register an app and use authentication? That seems like overkill. Additionally my page is all client side and it looks like there's a 15 request limit on that method and it's not intended to be called repetitively. Should I just hardcode the current max length plus a few chars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hardcoded the max length of my tweet to 140 - 25. 140 was the max tweet length. 20 was the max length of a t.co url at the time, and I sacrificed 5 additional characters to reduce the chance of it breaking if they added additional characters, which it looks like they have, so good call me! It's now up to 22 chars for http links.